# Indica petrol 2006,coolant leakege

Tags: cooling-system, hvac, coolant-leak

I have bought a 2006 petrol Indica Xeta,and changed the normal radiator water with valvoline super koolextra. After 50km of driving, I kept the vehicle in my car porch. After 5 days When I opened the door for a new trip,I have noticed that the newly filled coolant was flowing down into the driver side platform. It was about 1 litres. I have add normal water in to the reservoir and started the engine. My radiator fan is working normally, but higly hot air is comming from the engine room and the water circulation is normal. After stopping the engine, I have noticed that some type of clear water drops coming down to the ground through the outlet hose from the black coloured box located near the clutch pedal, inside the vehicle. the black box was hot while the engine running. please tell me that how the coolant leaked in to inside the car and how can it rectified ?.

Comment: Is there any leak outside the car?

Comment: no the water is comming down to the ground through the outlet hose from the heater core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the leak is only inside the vehicle:

There are 2 tubes that allow the coolant to flow in and out through the firewall. These tubes send heated coolant to the heater core inside your dash to provide the inside of your car with heat. If it is leaking inside the car, then either one of these tubes has a hole in it, or your heater core is has a leak. (its probably more likely the heater core is leaking)

Comment: Yes, I think my heater core is has a leak because the water drop is still comming from the outlet overflow tube.

Comment: There are two options to select, one is to replace the heater core and the other is to disconnect these tubes from the heater core and connect these them together with a steel connector.(This bypass method is only advisable to old cars.)